# Change default font to custom fonts in whole app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, fonts

I want to keep custom fonts in iOS app. Currently, I'm using iOS default fonts.
Is there any possible way for the same?

How do I include the custom font so that I can use it?

Answer (score 15):

Make a category:

```
#import "UILabel+Helper.h"

@implementation UILabel (Helper)
- (void)setSubstituteFontName:(NSString *)name UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR {
     self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:self.font.pointSize]; } 
@end
```

Then in AppDelegate.m:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setSubstituteFontName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular"];
```

This will change font in whole app even on `UIButton`, `UILabel`, inside `UITableViewCell`, `UICollectionViewCell`, `UIView`, `UIContainerView`, or anywhere in application without changing the font point size.

This is memory efficient approach rather than enumerating all views in your `UIViewController`.

Comment: this is awesome, by far the best approach

Comment: The best implementation. Thanks for the code, mate. Cheers!

Comment: this code works for me. But i have faced another problem. I want to change font family for certain UILabel in different controller( for eg: title). am using this code self.reg3.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"diff_font_name" size:30]. I just debug the code, it sets correctly. but after that it will change to App delegate font family name. the following code will execute at end of the debugging(After setting different font_name to UILabel)[[UILabel appearance] setSubstituteFontName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular"]

Comment: How can I modify it if I don't want to change fonts of a particular view?

Comment: @M.SherazLeo you have to explicitly change font of those particular views via code then. :)

Comment: @Xeieshan i have explicitly changed the font of a label via code but it is still using font used in AppDelegate for the whole app.

Comment: @Xeieshan it worked. I have used "setSubstituteFontName" method for that particular label and provided a different font. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

1. Copy your font file into resources
2. Add a key to your Info.plist file called `UIAppFonts`. ("Fonts provided
   by application")
3. Make this key an array
4. For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file
   (including the extension) as items to the `UIAppFonts` array
5. Save Info.plist
6. Now in your application you can simply call following method to get the custom font to use with your `UILabel` and `UITextView`, etc…

`[UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFontName" size:15];`

### ***Check which fonts are available in your resources :***

```
func allFonts(){
   for family in UIFont.familyNames(){
       println(family)
       for name in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family.description)
       {
           println("  \(name)")
       }
   }
}
```

### ***Change font for whole application in `UILabel` :***

Add code in **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     ...
     [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:17]];
     ...
}
```

### ***Change font in one `viewConroller` same as font size set in view design:***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setFontFamily:@"YourFontName" forView:self.view andSubViews:YES];
}

-(void)setFontFamily:(NSString*)fontFamily forView:(UIView*)view andSubViews:(BOOL)isSubViews
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)view;
        [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:[[lbl font] pointSize]]];
    }

    if (isSubViews)
    {
        for (UIView *sview in view.subviews)
        {
            [self setFontFamily:fontFamily forView:sview andSubViews:YES];
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Best from all... Thanks Ashish

Comment: @AshishKakkad Is there a way to change fonts by localisation, Like Poppins for English and Calibari for Arabic language? I want to change it throughout application from AppDelegate and not on specification UIViewController.

Comment: @Nij You have to check language before setting font that which language selected right now.

Answer (score 1):

1- Drag & Drop Font file .ttf to your project

2- Verify the font is in the project.

By selecting the font, and verifying “Target Membership” in the Utilities area.

[image]

3- Add info in plist
[image: Plist file image]

4- In delegate add this code

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:11.0]];

[[UITextField appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:11.0]];

[[UITextView appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:11.0]];
```

I hope this will help

Comment: this solution looks good, but it's uncompleted. I mean, the delegate class is so huge. Where does this code located in?? I'm using swift4, and I don't know where I can write it, because I have a lot of compilation problems. Can you write down the exact piece of code? thxs in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from all the other answers you are now very well familier that how to add a custom font (other than iOS default font) into app.

So now what? One thing is still remaining, I'm not sure if you want to use the same size custom font everywhere. If so,

I'm using this way to have custom font in my app.

**If your app will have a single custom font then you can use it like this way for entire app.**

```
#define appFontBold(x) [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont-Bold" size:x]
#define appFontLight(x) [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustonFont-Light" size:x]
#define appFontRegular(x) [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustonFont-Regular" size:x]
```

I've added these macros globally (so can access it from anywhere)

and you can use it like this, `yourLabel.font = appFontRegular(12);` or `yourTextField.font = appFontBold(14);` this helps you in following situations,

1. Whenever you needs to change the custom font, you only need to change font name in macros.
2. Your code will looks clean, no need write `[UIFont fontWithName: size:]`; everywhere.

**If your app will have more than one custom font then you can use it like this way for entire app.**

then also you can define different macros like this,

Then above macro will be the same (as this is the maximum used fonts in app), for other fonts :

```
#define appFontBoldOtherFont(x) [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomOtherFont-Bold" size:x]
#define appFontLightOtherFont(x) [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustonOtherFont-Light" size:x]
#define appFontRegularOtherFont(x) [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustonOtherFont-Regular" size:x]
```

Comment: great answer. this will also help me.

Answer (score -1):

Add your custom font into your project , i.e. Dragged the font file(CALIBRIZ_0.TTF) into XCode project.

Edit `Info.plist`: Add a new entry with the key "`Fonts provided by application`".

For each of your files, add the file name to this `array`

Now set font to your `label`

```
yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:15];
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change all fonts for all UILabel in one place, you need to create a category of UILabel.

for example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (AppFont)

@end


@implementation UILabel (AppFont)

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourCustomFont" size:self.font.pointSize];
}


@end
```

after you've created the category, you will need to import this class for all the file, or you can add it to '.pch' file for your project.

same solution for buttons / textview ..

Comment: Never override a method using a category. It's undefined behavior. And this code assumes all labels are created through nibs. This won't help for any labels created through code.