# How to use Arabic Custom Fonts in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, xcode8, arabic

How can i use A Jannat LT Arabic font in my working ios application .I am working with objective c in xcode 8 .I need to use these fonts through out in myProject and from where i get (.ttf) file ? .I Searched a lot but i couldnt find a proper answer ,Kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Arabic font in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691567/custom-arabic-font-in-ios)

Comment: What have you tried already that needs a fix? Please share some code.

Comment: its duplicate question     :::check this link :               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730658/change-default-font-to-custom-fonts-in-whole-app

Comment: @ olaia A Jannat LT i need this font . but from where i get .ttf of A Jannat LT font

Comment: That is a completely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow these steps**

1.) Drag fonts into your project.

2.) Define your fonts name in your plist. Open plist > right click > add row > type : `Fonts provided by application` > press + > yourFontName.ttf.

```
It look like this in info plist

Fonts provided by application  : Array : (2 items)

item 0 : fontNameOne.ttf
item 1 : fontNameTwo.ttf
```

3.) Either you can check it from storyboard or you can do programmatically.

```
yourLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFont" size:16.0f];//do not use .ttf here
```

Answer (score 1):

My question is do you need the font or do you need the way to implement it
[I think this is a nice explanation on how to add a custom font](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

If you need the font itself [let me google it for you](https://www.google.de/search?q=itself&rlz=1C5CHFA_enMD708MD710&oq=itself&aqs=chrome..69i57.613j0j4&%7Bgoogle:bookmarkBarPinned%7Dsourceid=chrome&%7Bgoogle:omniboxStartMarginParameter%7Die=UTF-8#q=ttf+download+A+Jannat+LT+Arabic&*)

***Update***

Not always the file name will coincide with the font family/font name, in order to check what Font families you have in your code you can use

**Swift3**

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("\(family)")
        for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
            print("== \(names)")
        }
    }
```

**Obj-C**

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family]) {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

Please use the link i gave to you in order to check if it works as expected

Comment: I need this font  A Jannat LT , this is one arabic font name ,    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"A Jannat LT " size:24];but it is not working

Comment: I updated my response, most likely the file name and the font name are not the same